# Как правильно заменить alert?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть алерт, который вызывается вот так:

```
   if(res.Poss < min || res.Poss > max) {
    alert('Incorrectly');
    return false;
}
```

Есть отдельный скрипт модального окна, который вызывается вот так:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
$('#modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    inst.open();
});

if ($('#updated').length) {
    inst.open();
}
```

});

То есть при наличии в коде div-а updated появляется модальное окно data-remodal-id=modal

Как правильно заменить alert('Incorrectly'); на вызов модального окна (data-remodal-id=modal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы модальное окно открывалось в скрипте вместо алерта, все скрипты необходимые для открытия модального окна должны быть выше, чем написанный ниже код (должно работать при условии, что у этого скрипта нет конфликтов с jquery):

```
var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
if(res.Poss < min || res.Poss > max) {
    inst.open();
}
```

Comment: Все работает, но проблема такая.
Добавил вот так:
    if(res.Poss < min || res.Poss  > max) {
     var inst = $("[data-remodal-id=er]").remodal();
        inst.open();
    return false;
    }

Проблема в том, что повторно не открывается окно. То есть 1 раз отобразилось, закрыл, второй раз нажимаешь - не появляется.

Comment: Ошибка вот такая - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: Трудно сказать из-за чего возникает ошибка без полного понимания работы скрипта с кодом, но в любом случае эта строка "var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();" должна обрабатываться в скрипте только 1 раз, а не при каждом срабатывания условия, ну и в "return false" нет особой необходимости в данном коде